# Cannot find "virtual applications and directories" configuration on Microsoft Azure web app

Tags: web, azure

I'm trying to set up a web app on Azure coded with Laravel
according to [this guide](https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-azure-web-app-b55e12514c46). 
Paragraph 3 under Step 5 in the guide refers to a section called
"**Virtual applications and directories**" in "**Application Settings**". 
My problem is that I don't find that section in the Azure portal for web applications.  Setting the "public directory" parameter in this section is necessary to properly reach the web content.

Could someone provide me some information about this?

Comment: Was this a linux instance or a windows one ? I am having problems in finding `Virtual application and directories` in a linux environment, and it looks like it's just not supported for Linux